# How to edit HTML in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms, webmatrix, html-editor

The HTML editor which comes with Orchard is not very user friendly - no tabbing, no coloration, no indention.

I downloaded the website files with WebMatrix to find the actual "view" files, but no luck. Also, opened the project in Visual Studios to do a search, but no luck.

I'm forced to concluding that the "content" of my Orchard Website is stored in a cloud database, and there is no way way for me to edit any of this "content" unless I'm in the DASHBOAD view of Orchard.

How can I edit HTML in Orchard CMS using another HTML editor than the one provided in DASHBOARD view?

Comment: Windows Live Writer can open pages with the right module from the gallery.

Comment: After some research, it seems that the Module available in Orchard gallery is not compatible with the new version of Orchard. I was not able to actually test it because while I was able to link a Blog with Live Writer, I was not able to figure out how to access the HTML content on a regular Page.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Yes, of course the contents is stored in the database, like it is in any CMS. There is a choice of  several online editors, from the built-in TinyMCE to the CK editor, and including Markdown and TinyMCE Deluxe. There is also a module that enables page edition from Live Writer: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.RemotePages. What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try Opening the page in WebMatrix and looking for the file there. WebMatrix has a fairly robust HTML editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sublime Text for your HTML edits and then copy and paste into Orchard